# python csv module read data from header

Tags: python, csv

I have following format of file

```
# Data set number 1 
#
# Number of lines 4010
# Max number of column 3 is 5
# Blahblah
# More blahblah
1 2 1 110 
2 2 5 20 21 465 417 38
2 1 2 33 46 17
......
4010 3 5 1001 2010 3355 107 2039
# Data set number 2 
#
# Number of lines 4010
# Max number of column 3 is 5
# Blahblah
# More blahblah
1 2 1 110 
2 2 5 20 21 465 417 38
2 1 2 33 46 17
......
```

I hope to read the number of data set, number of lines, and maximum number of column 3. I searched and find out csv module can read the headers, but can I read those numbers of header, and store? What I did was

```
nnn = linecache.getline(filename, 1)
nnnn = nnn(line.split()[4])
number = linecache.getline(filename, 3)
number2 = number(line.split()[4])
mmm = linecache.getline(filename, 5)
mmmm = mmm(line.split()[7])
mmmmm = int(mmmm)
max_nb = range(mmmmm)
n_data = int(nnnn)
n_frame = range(n_data)
singleframe = natoms + 6
```

Like this. How can I read those numbers and store using csv module? I skip the 6 headerlines by using 'singleframe', but also curious how csv module can read 6 number of header lines. Thanks

Comment: there is no need for csv here

Comment: Not sure what you expected `linecache` to do for you here; it is a Python source code introspection tool, not a generic package.

Comment: @njzk2 Hmm them just use linecache and line split is fine?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The reason why I used linecache is to read specificx lines of header lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have a CSV file; you have a proprietary format instead. Just parse it directly, using regular expressions to quickly extract your desired data:

```
import re

set_number = re.compile(r'Data set number (\d+)'),
patterns = {
    'line_count': re.compile(r'Number of lines (\d+)'),
    'max_num': re.compile(r'Max number of column 3 is (\d+)'),
}

with open(filename, 'r') as infh:
    results = {}
    set_numbers = []

    for line in infh:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            # skip lines without a comment
            continue

        set_match = set_number.match(line)
        if set_match:
            set_numbers.append(int(set_match.group(1)))
        else:
            for name, pattern in patterns.items():
                match = pattern.search(line)
                if match:
                    results[name] = int(match.group(1))
```

Do not use the `linecache` module. It'll read the whole file into memory, and is really only intended for access to Python source files; whenever a traceback needs to be printed this module caches the source files involved with the current stack. You'd only use it for smaller files from which you need random lines, repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about linecache. In my file, my data set number will be array, but number of lines and max number of column 3 is single number. How can I store this? Just like 'nlines = 4010'

Comment: @user1798797: you mean you need to read all the `Data set` lines?

Comment: @user1798797: the code will now read *all* `Data set` numbers, collecting them into a list.

Comment: I hope to get "n_data = 2390 (since there are 2390 number of 'data set' in my file)" and get "n_lines = 4010". I can make array by using "ary = range(n_data)" But I just hope to store those number of data, number of lines to single name

Comment: @user1798797: sorry, I cannot make much sense of that. Perhaps you can update your question with the expected output?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will study what you wrote for me first. Then I will ask maybe. Thanks anyway